# How do I make my css class footer go from the left to right side of the screen?

Tags: css, background, footer, background-repeat

My CSS class footer does not expand the entire bottom of the page.  It works properly if the browser window is small enough, but if the window is large enough the right and left side end and the page background is visible.  The class is not nested in another class and its only parents are the  and  tags.  Here is the css for footer:

```
.Footer { width: 100%; padding:10px 0; margin:0px 0 0 0; text-align:center; border-top:1px solid #b3b3b3; background-color:#d9d9d9;}
.Footer p { color:#959595; padding:0; margin:0; font:normal 10px 'Verdana';}
.Footer a { color:#959595; text-decoration:underline;}
```

The page is up at avidest.com so you can see what I mean.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Footer` block outside of your main container, `bgRasize`, and it should span the width of the page. It's currently 100% width of it's container.

```
<div class="bgRasize">
  ... other content
</div>

<div class="Footer">
  ... footer content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That took care of the left side of the footer, but now if the page is too small and the user scrolls to the right, the footer will still end before it is supposed to and also the text in the footer is not moving with the rest of the page.  Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Set the `min-width` of the `.Footer` to whatever the size of your main container width i.e. `min-width: 1024px;`

Answer (score 1):

Check for three things:

1. The `.Footer` element is a direct child of your `<body>` tag.
2. The `<body>` should have `padding: 0; margin: 0;` if you want to ensure your element will touch the edges of the viewport.
3. If the element with class `.Footer` is not a block element by default you should explicitly set its display style to `display: block;`.

The tag hierarchy should look like this:

```
<body>
  <!-- Page content. -->
  <div class="Footer"></div>
</body>
```